# how to use $compile in angular component angular 1.5 and above

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am migrating from directive to component but error is getting while using $compile As :

```
$compile(ReturnDomElement)(scope);
```

What should be used instead Of $scope As I dont injected $scope in my component.

Comment: You don't need to convert all your directives to components. Components do not need a compile option. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: for Upgrading to angular 2.0 in future And for that component should be favored as a replacement to directive,I am simply converting my directive to a component which contains use of $compile for the dynamic template/DOM.

Comment: No, you misunderstand components. They are not a replacement for directives. It's a way to architect an application. DOM manipulation will always be done through directives. Components are here to structure your app. There is no reasonable way to answer your question. A directive shouldn't be converted to a component.

Comment: okay gyc, you mean to say i dont need to convert the directive into component instead I should keep using the directive.

Comment: Yes, and the logic should be moved from divs+controllers to components